# If using a query builder as to what in the form of its laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, subquery

I have a query sql like the following may be a bit complex, I am a bit of trouble to convert into a for framework laravel. Please help for everything with framework laravel query results. My problem here is, I do not know how to create a sub select query to laravel framework. Thanks guys.

```
SELECT
 lin_users.status_employee_id,
  lin_users.id,
  lin_users.username,
  lin_users.created,
  lin_users.modified,
  lin_employee_attributes.unit_code,
  lin_employee_attributes.position_code,
  lin_employee_attributes.begin_date,
  lin_employee_attributes.end_date,
  contactnumber.contact_id as phone_number,
  contactmobile.contact_id as cell_number,
  contactemail.contact_id as email

FROM lin_users
  INNER JOIN lin_status_employees
    ON lin_users.status_employee_id = lin_status_employees.id

  INNER JOIN lin_people
    ON lin_status_employees.person_id = lin_people.id

  INNER JOIN lin_employee_attributes
    ON lin_users.status_employee_id = lin_employee_attributes.status_employee_id

  LEFT JOIN lin_contacts AS contactnumber
    ON lin_people.id = contactnumber.person_id AND contactnumber.contact_type = 'Work Telephone'

  LEFT JOIN lin_contacts AS contactmobile
    ON lin_people.id = contactmobile.person_id AND contactmobile.contact_type = 'Mobile'

  LEFT JOIN lin_contacts AS contactemail
    ON lin_people.id = contactemail.person_id AND contactemail.contact_type = 'Email'
WHERE lin_employee_attributes.begin_date = '2016-11-07'
      OR lin_employee_attributes.end_date = '2017-10-21'
GROUP BY lin_users.id,
  lin_employee_attributes.unit_code,
  lin_employee_attributes.position_code,
  lin_employee_attributes.begin_date,
  lin_employee_attributes.end_date, lin_people.id,
  contactnumber.contact_id,
  contactmobile.contact_id,
  contactemail.contact_id;
```

Comment: I recommend to use these raw query. Laravel's Eloquent is a query builder, which is not so efficient as a optimised raw query. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries

Comment: I've tried using the query, but the results:
`SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from users where id = $1
^ (SQL: select * from users where id = 1)`

Though the user table in the database there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this work. Finally, with the above query can be solved with the concept query to query in laravel.

```
$users = $this->db->getTable('users')
            ->select('users.status_employee_id',
                     'users.id',
                     'users.username',
                     'users.email',
                     'users.created',
                     'users.modified',
                     'users.flag_delete',
                     'employee_attributes.unit_code',
                     'employee_attributes.position_code',
                     'employee_attributes.begin_date',
                     'employee_attributes.end_date',
                     'contactnumber.contact_id as phone_number',
                     'contactmobile.contact_id as cell_number',
                     'contactemail.contact_id as email'
                    )
            ->join('status_employees', 'users.status_employee_id', '=', 'status_employees.id')
            ->join('people', 'status_employees.person_id', '=', 'people.id')
            ->join('employee_attributes', 'users.status_employee_id', '=', 'employee_attributes.status_employee_id')
            ->leftJoin('contacts AS contactnumber', function($join)
                     {
                         $join->on('people.id', '=', 'contactnumber.person_id');
                         $join->on('contactnumber.contact_type','=', DB::raw("'Work Telephone'"));
                     })
             ->leftJoin('contacts AS contactmobile', function($join)
                     {
                          $join->on('people.id', '=', 'contactmobile.person_id');
                          $join->on('contactmobile.contact_type','=', DB::raw("'Mobile'"));
                     })
              ->leftJoin('contacts AS contactemail', function($join)
                     {
                         $join->on('people.id', '=', 'contactemail.person_id');
                         $join->on('contactemail.contact_type','=', DB::raw("'Email'"));
                     })

            ->where(function ($query) use ($begin_date, $end_date) {
                $query->where('employee_attributes.begin_date', $begin_date)
                      ->orWhere('employee_attributes.end_date', $end_date);
            })
            ->groupby('users.status_employee_id',
                      'users.id',
                      'users.username',
                      'users.email',
                      'users.created',
                      'users.modified',
                      'users.flag_delete',
                      'employee_attributes.unit_code',
                      'employee_attributes.position_code',
                      'employee_attributes.begin_date',
                      'employee_attributes.end_date',
                      'contactnumber.contact_id',
                      'contactmobile.contact_id',
                      'contactemail.contact_id'
                    )
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const TABLE = 'my_table_name';

return $this
    ->select(
        self::TABLE . 'id as myidalias',
        self::TABLE . 'username as myuseralias') 
    ->addSelect(DB::raw(
        "
        (your custom select here) as mycustomresult
        "
    ));
```

You can add as many addSelect as you want. Also when you have a lot of complex queries like this, a lot of times you have duplicated parts on them so I highly recommend using [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) it makes your code clean and reusable.

```
public function scopeLeftJoinCategory($query)
{
    return $query
            ->leftJoin(Category::CONTENTS_CATEGORIES . ' AS cc', 'con.id', '=', 'cc.content_id')
            ->leftJoin(Category::TABLE . ' AS cat', 'cc.category_id', '=', 'cat.id');
}
```

Then you just use it like this: `->leftJoinCategory()`

Comment: Thanks Zoltán Jére, I try to implement it. I hope it can to solve the problem.

Comment: I also recommend adding https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

You can see the final query what laravel have built up with your code. You can copy and run it manually which can help finding the wrong part, if the query doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Great tools laravel-DebugBar, I try to install in the project laravel.